# Error in `./main': free(): invalid pointer : using sd_vector of library SDSL-lite

Tags: c++, free

I'm currently trying to exchange my rrr_vector to sd_vector in my programm (using SDSL-lite libray) and I'm having some issues with a "Error in `./main': free(): invalid pointer" error.

Here is some of my code :

```
void Anno::setLink(bit_vector l){
cout << "l : "<<  l << endl;
sd_vector<> sdvec(l);
this->link = sdvec;
cout << "link : " <<this->link << endl; 
}
```

This code was perfectly working while using the rrr_vectors :

```
void Anno::setLink(bit_vector l){
cout << "l : "<<  l << endl;
rrr_vector<127> rrrvec(l);
this->link = rrrvec;
cout << "link : " <<this->link << endl; 
}
```

The error appends while doing the equality.
For course, I changed the type of the variable this->link in the Anno class.

I tried using the swap function of the library (which swap the values of sdvec and this->link) but I still have the error while ending the function setLink.

A valgrind execution indicates the following error :

```
==6736== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6736==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in 
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6736==    by 0x40C8CA: free_mem (memory_management.hpp:316)
==6736==    by 0x40C8CA: void 
sdsl::memory_manager::clear<sdsl::int_vector<(unsigned char)0> >
(sdsl::int_vector<(unsigned char)0>&) [clone .isra.213] 
(memory_management.hpp:377)
==6736==    by 0x4135DA: ~int_vector (int_vector.hpp:1296)
==6736==    by 0x4135DA: sdsl::select_support_mcl<(unsigned char)0, 
(unsigned char)1>::copy(sdsl::select_support_mcl<(unsigned char)0, 
(unsigned char)1> const&) (select_support_mcl.hpp:183)
==6736==    by 0x440EDC: operator= (select_support_mcl.hpp:134)
==6736==    by 0x440EDC: copy (sd_vector.hpp:169)
==6736==    by 0x440EDC: operator= (sd_vector.hpp:383)
```

Does any of you have an idea to help me debug my code?
I'll appreciate any little help/idea (and sorry for my english)
Have a good day.

Comment: any MWE??????????

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: I suspect that `this` doesn't point to something valid.

Comment: BTW: that's an assignment. Equality is `==`.

Comment: _"Does any of you have an idea to help me debug my code?"_ Yes: Use a debugger. Or tell valgrind to show you the callers that lead to the invalid conditions.